# libnm - What are the necessary steps to create a hotspot?

Tags: c, networkmanager

I want to create a hotspot network using libnm in C. I tried following the following steps:

1. Connect to NetworkManager using `nm_client_new(NULL, NULL);`
2. Get the wlan device `nm_client_get_device_by_iface(client, "wlan0");`
3. Create the connection `nm_simple_connection_new()`:
4. `nm_setting_connection_new()` with `g_object_set("type", "802-11-wireless", "uuid", HOTSPOT_UUID, "id", "MyHotspot", "autoconnect", FALSE);` and added to connection
5. `nm_setting_wireless_new()` with mode=adhoc, ssid=MyHotspotSSID
6. `nm_setting_ip4_config_new()` with method=shared
7. `nm_setting_ip6_config_new()` with method=ignore
8. `nm_setting_wireless_security_new()` with key-mgmt=none, wep-key0=key_str, wep-key-type=NM_WEP_KEY_TYPE_KEY
9. `nm_client_add_and_activate_connection_async(client, connection, wlan_device, NULL, NULL, on_connection_added, loop);`, loop being a GMainLoop.
10. `g_main_loop_run(loop);`

After those steps are done, it seemingly finishes instantly, but for some reason, there is no new connection and is not activated. Callback of `nm_client_add_and_activate_connection_async` never getting called. I also tried without wep-key0 or the loop, just waiting for the callback, none of which worked.

Am I missing some steps? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: In the `on_connection_added`, I am calling `nm_client_add_and_activate_connection_finish(NM_CLIENT(source_object), res, &error)` but may not matter since the callback is never reached. I also call `g_main_loop_quit(user_data);` after the `_finish` function.

Comment: Very nice ;-)
Would you mind sharing an excerpt of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the issue, I did take the correct steps, but the actual code was unreachable. This took a genuinly long timr to figure out what was wrong. Sorry for spamming the forum!

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue - when you say it was unreachable, what do you mean? I'm not using a loop and instead just waiting for the callback to be called (so truly async), and it never gets called. The callback is in the same module and they aren't in a unique thread. Just curious if you have more details

Comment: In my case, the function that was creating and activating the hotspot, was not called, it included all the steps in my question, except the client_new which was called in my main function. Sorry, but I do not have any more details about this